# Trek 7100 multitrack

Tags: trek, hybrid-bike

I am looking to buy a used hybrid.  Its a Trek 7100 multitrack. How can I find out what years trek made this bike?  And how can I find the current value? Bicycle Blue Book doesn't list the Trek 7100 multitrack and the vintage trek site doesn't either.

Comment: Product valuations are off-topic here because they're of limited use and are highly localised.  Generally speaking, a bike is worth what someone wants to pay for it, so compare with other local listings on ebay/craigslist.  Pay more for good condition, less for bad, more for known history, less for unknown history.  And never pay more than 1/3 of new-equivalent retail cost,

Answer (score 0):

Bikepedia list the Trek 7100 as having been in production from 2002-2012. In some cases you can determine the year of production by seeing which color combinations or components were available for a particular year. Bicycle values are difficult to state as they change over time and can vary greatly by geographic area. The msrp was highest at the mid $400 range. Your best bet is to look at similar bikes with similar component levels and compare price and condition.

.